# How to update and reply at the same time for an interaction, discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, embed

I'm experiencing an interaction error **interaction has already been acknowledged** when attempting to update and reply. This is because I already replied to the interaction through update/reply once.

What I want to do is when a user clicks the button on an embed message, the embed message gets updated/edited and then a hidden/ephemeral message is also sent.

1. Embed with button is shown.
2. User clicks the button.
3. Embed gets updated with new title.
4. User gets a ephemeral reply saying "Success".

Here's the interaction code:

```
client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.customId === "button") {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("This is a new title")
         interaction.update({embeds: [embed]});
         await interaction.reply({content: "Succcess!", ephemeral: true});
    }
})
```

Comment: Try using `interaction.followUp(...)` instead of `reply`

Comment: @clapmemereview, it says [InteractionNotReplied]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ButtonInteraction#followUp()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=followUp) method instead. Note that the [`ButtonInteraction#update()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=update) must be awaited so it has time to internally set [`ButtonInteraction#replied`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=replied) to true. If not, you will get the `InteractionNotReplied` error.

```js
await interaction.update({ embeds: [embed] });
await interaction.followUp({ content: "Succcess!", ephemeral: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a `messageComponentCollector` in the code of your command that sends the original embed, which will act as a mini-event emitter for the components that are active in a specific channel, such as buttons.

```
client.on("messageCreate", async (msg) => {
  if (msg.content === "!ping") {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder().setTitle("Amazing embed");

    const botMsg = await msg.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

    const collector = msg.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
      /* Collector settings, see https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/MessageComponentCollectorOptions */
    });
    collector.on("collect", async (buttonInteraction) => {
      if (buttonInteraction.customId === "button") {
        await buttonInteraction.reply({ content: "Success!", ephemeral: true });
        embed.setTitle("New amazing title");
        await botMsg.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
      }
    });
  }
});
```